# Powershell: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: powershell

This may be something so easy but I cannot figure out why its not working. See below:

```
$regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments\" + $idString

$regPath

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {Remove-Item -Path $regPath -Force -Verbose}
```

I am essentially trying to remove a registry entry under a particular path. When I output `$regPath` and copy & paste it manually into the path parameter, it accepts it and runs as normal. Despite this, when I want to provide the variable with the same path, it produces the error in the title - appears to be null. I have checked the documentation and it says `-path` is a String...which the information I am providing is. I'm really not sure why it is not accepting it.

Comment: `$regPath` doesn't exist on the remote machine. Do `{Remove-Item -Path $using:regPath -Force -Verbose}` to instruct PowerShell to copy the variable to the remote scope

Comment: Thank you. Still trying to learn powershell